# Are MongoDB data files OS or File System dependent?

Tags: mongodb

We are wanting to move a MongoDB database from Linux Ext4 to Windows NTFS. We prefer not to do a dump of the database and would rather copy the files. We are doing a simple copy of the directory, keeping data and timestamps, and leaving out everything else:

> cp -r --preserve=timestamps /mnt/ext4-drive/* /mnt/ntfs-drive

The NTFS drive is then physically moved to the new server and copied to a local drive (both are NTFS):

> robocopy e:\ d:\ /e /copy:DT

As you can see, when copying the files we are excluding all but the data and timestamps. I could not think of a reason why MongoDB would be dependent on filesystem details such as attributes on a file, but felt keeping timestamps on the files may be of importance.

So ultimately, the question, is MongoDB dependent on the filesystem or OS details for each MongoDB data folder, or is the data folder able to be copied between different OS's and FileSystems without issue?

Answer (score 1):

The dbPath files shall not depend on backend operating system and file system. As far as the mongod version is same there must be no issues , also dbPath files timestamp does not metter , important is the files content ...